# Automatic groups based on table titles

Tags: csv, excel-formula

I have a huge csv dataset that consists of similar tables.  The structure of my data is shown is like the dummy data below, where **'Weekday:XY' is an example table and all tables are square**:

[image]

**I would like to automatically make expandable groups based on table titles.** So I need something that looks like this:

[image]

The above is done manually with Data>Group>Rows.
Would anyone have any ideas of how this can be done efficiently?

Thanks!